# Website surfacing blank pages in IE6

Tags: php, http, xhtml, internet-explorer-6, explorer

*- Since discovering more about my problem I have modified my question*

A single user is complaining that (on XP and using IE6) they're not able to follow any links around my site. The behaviour they're seeing is clicking a link shows a blank page, but doesn't change the url in the address bar of the browser. Pressing refresh at this point then displays the page correctly with the correct URL in the address bar.

All anchors are correct, and as well as testing the site in all *our favourite* browsers I have also tested the site myself on XP using IE6 and have **no problems**.

Has anyone any thoughts on what could be causing this? Perhaps it could be the fact they're within a company network for example? -- I don't see how that could cause a problem, but I am so far coming up empty.

I'm using XHTML & PHP. Headers are being received correctly. I've also ensured full PHP error reporting is on and there are no errors.

Comment: It's possible to configure IE to not follow redirects (it's a "security" thing).  You could always stick a "Redirecting you to xxxx..." message with a link in the body of the page for anyone stupid enough to configure IE that way.

Comment: I have added a continue message as well as the JS (I perhaps could have mentioned that in the question) - but it comes up blank as if it doesn't attempt to render the page at all. Your suggestion about not following redirects due to a security decision is the kind of suggestion I was looking for. That sounds like a possibility, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was caused by a combination of the following two factors.

- Firstly, the user was behind a proxy at their workplace (an ISA server).
- Secondly, through debugging I found that the following two meta tags in the HTML head were the cause.

.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
```

Basically IE appears to just give up once it reaches these two lines. Viewing source didn't work so it was not possible to see this directly.

The website worked fine when only either one of the two factors were present, but when combined they caused the problem.

So to solve my problem I removed these two lines. Now the site works fine.

Answer (score 1):

The header should work alone (I see nothing wrong with it).

The JavaScript however is wrong since the HTML comments `<!--` and `-->` aren't valid JavaScript instructions and so all you'll get will be a parse error. You must first *comment the comments* (like `//<!--` and `//-->`).

I hope that at least fixing the workaround helps!

Comment: The HTML comments there are for the old trick of stopping v. old browsers getting confused by the javascript. It was slightly wrong though, corrected now.